# this is the code for my manage.py script i would like someone to explain each line please i barely understand it

Tags: django

```
import os
import sys


def main():
    """Run administrative tasks."""
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'bookr.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the code works i just do not understand why

Answer (score 2):

In one sentence: manage.py is the entry point for django management commands.

A few more words to explain the context:

the django framework is designed to be "served" by a webserver like apache to which it is linked via the wsgi.py interface. So Apache would get a web request and then call django via the mod_wsgi.

```
.... a rough path:
Browser 
 -> Web Request
  -> Apache (mod_wsgi)
   -> python interpreter
    -> wsgi.py 
     -> setup django (settings.py/DB connection ...) 
      -> url routing 
       -> view
       <- return response HTTP
     <- Apache
    <- Browser
```

For some cases it is useful to execute adminstration or development things from command line on the server with a fully setup django but not via Browser e.g.

- migrate models to database
- run a local development server for debugging
- test code in a easy way
- move data from legacy database to django models via python script
  ....

This "entry" to django is the manage.py script via that the so called "management commands" are started

```
-> python manage.py xyz
 -> import and setup django (settings.py/DB connection ...) 
  -> call the xyz management command
   ->
```

A management command is always in a folder
app_name/management/command/xyz.py

and has to implement

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        ....

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ....
        here is the code
```

see also https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/custom-management-commands/