# error : django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured

Tags: python, django, apscheduler

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

When I run the testapscheduler.py file, I get the above error.
Is it because I only run one file in the Dajngo frame that I get the above error?
How can I test it?

**testapscheduler.py**:

```
import logging
from models import Todo
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz
import requests


def notify_todo():
    # 現在の日時を取得
    now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Asia/Tokyo'))

    # 締め切りが30分以内のTODOリストを取得
    todos = Todo.objects.filter(
        deadline__gt=now - timedelta(minutes=30),
        deadline__lt=now + timedelta(minutes=30),
        ttime__isnull=False,
        ttime__gt=now.time()
    )

# 30分以内のTODOリストの数を出力
    # ログの出力名を設定
    logger = logging.getLogger('mylog')

    #ログレベルを設定
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    #ログをコンソール出力するための設定
    sh = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger.addHandler(sh)

    logger.debug(f'{len(todos)}個のTODOリストが締め切り30分以内にあります。')


    for todo in todos:
        #LINE NotifyのAPIトークンを取得
        api_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        
        # 通知メッセージの作成
        message = f"【{todo.title}】\n締切時間：{todo.deadline.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')}\n詳細：{todo.description}"

        # LINE Notifyに通知を送信
        headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_token}'}
        payload = {'message': message}
        requests.post('https://notify-api.line.me/api/notify', headers=headers, data=payload)

def start():
    scheduler =BackgroundScheduler(timezone='Asia/Tokyo')
    scheduler.add_job(notify_todo, 'interval', seconds=2) # 2秒ごとに実行
    scheduler.start()
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models


class Todo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField("タスク名", max_length=30)
    description = models.TextField("詳細", blank=True)
    deadline = models.DateField("締切")
    ttime = models.TimeField("")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

[image: directory]

Comment: Have you set the environment variable like `export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=your_project_name.settings` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED\_APPS, but settings are not configured](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50074690/improperlyconfigured-requested-setting-installed-apps-but-settings-are-not-con)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the standard way to execute a command from command line but within the django context: django management commands.

See the answer to this question [this is the code for my manage.py script i would like someone to explain each line please i barely understand it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75405739)

in your case code in start() needs to go into handle() function of the management command.

```
file: app_name/management/command/start.py
--------------

class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        return

    def handle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        scheduler =BackgroundScheduler(timezone='Asia/Tokyo')    
        scheduler.add_job(notify_todo, 'interval', seconds=2) # 2秒ごとに実行
        scheduler.start()


def notify_todo():
 .....
```

then just call the command by

```
> python manage.py start
```